# SwiftData - using @Query with a filter predicate does not work as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, swift-data

I am using SwiftData & SwiftUI. This is the rough setup of my code:

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query
    private var items: [Items]

    @State private var itemToEdit: Item?
    private var isEditing: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding { itemToEdit != nil }
        set: { _ in itemToEdit = nil }
    }

    var body: some View {
       NavigationStack{
           List(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        itemToEdit = item
                    }
           }
       }.navigationDestination(isPresented: isEditing) {
            if let item = itemToEdit {
                EditView(item: item)
            }
       }
    }
}
```

```
struct EditView: View {
    var item: Item
    ...
}
```

Now, this actually works fine. If I click on the text for an item, I go into the edit view and everything works well. However, if I change the @Query to add a filter like so:

```
@Query(filter: #Predicate<Item>{ $0.name != ""})
    private var items: [Item]
```

Then it no longer works. The list of items will be displayed, but if I click on any of them nothing happens and it seems like the app hangs. I also added some print statement and it seems like it is constantly creating the body of ListItemView for some reason.

On clicking on an item, I would expect that it navigates to EditView. For some reason, this is not the case but only when I add a filter predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're seemingly supporting at least iOS 16, I believe in your case, a better approach might be using a different initializer for the navigation destination:

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: Item.self, destination: { item in
    EditView(item: item)
})
```

This associates the navigation with the presented data type. The use of a boolean to determine the state that the `NavigationStack` should be in might not always be reliable, so having something like the item that is being selected in the List can be a little more easier to manage.

This should easily filter out using a predicate with your `Query`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem seems to be OS dependent but the issue is with `navigationDestination` in combination with the `Binding` property and also the `@Query`.

If we change the boolean property to be a `@State` property we can avoid the infinite loop of updates that otherwise occurred.

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Item>{ $0.name != ""})
    private var items: [Item]

    @State private var itemToEdit: Item?
    @State var isEditing = false // Changed declaration

    var body: some View {
       NavigationStack{
           List(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        itemToEdit = item
                       isEditing = true // Update the property here
                    }
           }
       }
       .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isEditing) {
            if let item = itemToEdit {
                EditView(item: item)
            }
       }
    }
}
```

If only iOS is supported we can use `.navigationDestination(item:)` and skip the `@State` property which gives us less code

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Item>{ $0.name != "" }) private var items: [Item]
    @State private var itemToEdit: Item?

    var body: some View {
       NavigationStack{
           List(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        itemToEdit = item
                    }
           }
       }
       .navigationDestination(item: $itemToEdit) {
           EditView(item: $0)
       }
    }
}
```